# HP iLO xmldata modification

Tags: monitoring, hp

I've just installed a HP Microserver Gen8 and I would like to monitor it (using Rainmeter).
Unfortunately I have restricted internet access (80/443) so I would like to use XML for this. I can get some basic information using:
https://myserver/xmldata?item=All
How could I modify this xml to have some more details (like temperature/memory/cpu etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not get this information. This interface is only for discovering.

Maybe this will help to get a little more data, but do you really what all information about the server without authentication?

Read

http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03334058

```
If configured to do so, the iLO device returns identifying information in 
response to an
unauthenticated XML query. By default, the iLO device is configured to 
return this information.
To disable this feature, set the CIM_SECURITY_MASK in the 
MOD_SNMP_IM_SETTINGS
command to disable unauthenticated XML query return information.
```

and

```
CIM_SECURITY_MASK accepts the integers 0–4. The possible values are:
• 0—No change
• 1—None (no data is returned)
• 2, 3, 4—Enabled (medium — 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but may help others.

*HPE Redfish, and hperest was implemented on Gen 8 (gen8's may need an updated ilo firmware to access this functionality) and Newer ProLiants 
This allows Collection of things like, CPU , POWER, Thermal etc over a Secure HTTPS connection**

- '@humans374 Your url indicated you have https access which allows you
  the ability to collect a Ton of information when utilizing various
  tools Take a look at'

https://www.hpe.com/us/en/product-catalog/detail/pip.scripting-tools-for-windows-powershell.5440657.html

There are powershell cmdlets for HPEREST, HPEREDFISh, HPEilo HPEOA, etc.
There are also extensive python and curl samples available.